# Animation In SpriteKit using skscene editor

Tags: animation, sprite-kit, xcode10

I want to use the skscene editor in order to create a simple two picture animation. Since Xcode 10 i cannot add any pictures/textures to the animation because of the missing library bar. (I am aware of the programmatically solution)[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can access the Media Library using CMD + Shift + M (or View > Libraries > Show Media library). Just open it and drag your textures as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the iPhone home button on the top towards the right? (It is a circle with a square inside)  That is where it is located at now.